# 13.10 with Mate and Clearlooks: some gtk apps are mostly black

Tags: 13.10, themes, mate

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 and wiping all configuration files and folders from my home directory, I chose "Clearlooks" as theme in `mate-appearance-properties`.

Most applications look nice, but some (maybe gtk2 ones?) are largely black, as if the theme is broken:[image]

`gucharmap` and `gitg` show the black elements, while `gtk-demo` looks totally fine.

What could the reason be, and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your misbehaving apps may be gtk3. To find out, run:

```
ldd /usr/bin/app_name | grep gtk
```

For example with `gucharmap`,

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/gucharmap | grep gtk
    libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007fcdee89a000)
$
```

Note `libgtk-3.0` in the output.

Also check with `whereis` in case your app is elsewhere such as in `sbin` instead of in `bin`.

The `Clearlooks` theme only supports gtk2. (Look in your `themes` folder and you won't see a gtk-3.0 subfolder in the Clearlooks folder.)

I suggest you use a theme that supports both gtk2 **and** gtk3.

Comment: You nailed it. I chose the "TraditionalOk" theme that looks similar to Clearlooks and supports gtk3.